# Get Value and Name of type A record of AWS route53 resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-route53

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id XXXXXXXXXXX --output text --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Type == 'A'].[Name,Value]"
```

I tried this its giving me name but in place of value its showing none.

Comment: `Value` isn't a top level attribute, it lives under `ResourceRecords`.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the `Value` property does not exist. I did a test with my hosted zones. All of my `A` records are pointing to CloudFront. Therefore I have an `AliasTarget` attribute.

```
// Alias Records
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id XXXXXXXXXXX --output text --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Type == 'A'].[Name, AliasTarget.DNSName]"
```

this gives me all the non-alias targets. If you have any `A` record that directly points to an IP address, the following should get the value for you.

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id XXXXXXXXXXX --output text --query "ResourceRecordSets[].[Name, ResourceRecords[0].Value]"
```

the following should cover both cases. But I am not sure how many other cases exist.

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id XXXXXXXXXXX --output text --query "ResourceRecordSets[].[Name, AliasTarget.DNSName || ResourceRecords[0].Value]"
```

hope this helps